# UE4 GC and memory : Why my material is still in memory?

Tags: garbage-collection, unreal-engine4

I used this code to change material for a component at runtime:

```
MeshComponent->SetMaterial(0, NewMaterial);
```

After that i called ue4 gc manually,then uesd "memreport -full" to monitor memory used. I was surprised to find the old material was still in memory. I can sure that no other component use the old material in raw scene.

What's more,i uesd "*FReferenceChainSearch*" to find that there was no reference with the old material at that time.

I don't know why the old material is still in memory. Are there any other possibilities that could cause this phenomenon?

Can anyone tell me why? Or how to change material for a component at runtime so that the old material can be unloaded correctly.

Comment: Are you running in editor or standalone?